# Liquid - parse YAML front matter in string

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid, yaml-front-matter

I'm running a Jekyll site that uses JSON as data in my `_data` folder. I'm looping through the file like normal doing things like `{% for item in site.data.resources.items %}` just fine. However, I'd like to parse YAML front matter that is within a string.

Example:

`\n---\nblog: http://google.com\nbackground-img: http://www.ew.com/sites/default/files/i/2013/07/23/Dumb-and-Dumber.jpg\nbuttonText: Download\n---\n`

How can I have Liquid parse this within my Jekyll site so I can use it like so:

`<a href="{{blog}}"><img src="{{background-img}}>Image</a>`

or something similar?

EDIT: To clarify, that string is in front matter format in a text file that I'm retrieving through an ajax call. So that string is the response I get back and the format won't be changing. My hope was that Liquid could somehow parse this string and look for a front matter type format. If not, I will revert back my JavaScript methods.

Comment: Are you asking how you can use yaml front matter to select your data items?

Comment: I'm not a developer, but is `background-img` and `buttonText` child key-value pairs of the `blog` item in that structure? If so, perhaps something like front matter entry `item: blog` and in content `<a href="{{ site.data.resources.items.[page.item] }}"><img src="{{site.data.resources.items.[page.item].background-img}}>Image</a>`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: What exactly does your frontmatter look like? That long string is actually a value in your frontmatter? Would the "contains" operator work? like, {% if page.url contains "nbackground-img" %} background-img {% endif %}. It's unclear exactly what your setup is.

Comment: @TomJohnson to clarify, that string is front matter format in a text file that I'm retrieving through an ajax call. So that string is the response I get back and the format won't be changing. My hope was that Liquid could somehow parse this string and look for a front matter type format. If not, I will revert back my JavaScript methods.

Comment: @TBB no, they are not child k-v pairs. I didn't format this because it's just a string and that's the way it is in my JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

**This is impossible.**

Liquid/YML is being parsed while generating the site and your JSON string comes available long after the site has been generated: It only exists after the moment the JSON request for the string has been succesful.

However, you can use javascript, as you already mentioned. Simply split the string on `\n` for your key-value pairs and split on `:` for your key and value. Then use jQuery (or plain javascript) to write the results to the DOM.

Good luck!

Comment: I use a Gulp task to pull that data first, then store it in a json file in my `_data` folder, then run my build command. So technically it's there. I guess I was hoping there was a way to get this done from within Liquid, but I'm starting to see this just isn't possible. Back to the drawling board with plenty of ways to solve this.